# Can't perform arithmetic operations on input in Python

Tags: python

I'll take any input.  Just started programming in Python and can't solve this error.

My simple code:

```
hourlyWage = input('Hourly Wage?')
weeklyHours = input('Weekly Hours?')
weeklyWage = hourlyWage * weeklyHours
print(weeklyWage)
```

The error:

```
"TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

I create two variables that a User can input, when I try to get the product of the two variables I get an error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `hourlyWage = int(input('Hourly Wage?'))` etc

Comment: Input will always be string. You need to conert it to integer. Use `int(hourlyWage)`

Comment: Being new is no excuse, your title should always have something to do with your actual question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response   :   A sking the user for input until they give a valid response    I liked this one very much

Answer (score 0):

The `input` function returns a `string`, so you need to convert it to a `float` like this:

```py
hourlyWage = float(input('Hourly Wage?'))
weeklyHours = float(input('Weekly Hours?'))
weeklyWage = hourlyWage * weeklyHours
print(weeklyWage)
```

Did you notice `float()`?  That converted your `string` to a `float`.  Now your program will work.

Comment: Instructions for how to mark an answer don't belong in the answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom : Got it, removed.

Answer (score -1):

Convert it to int first. (`input()` returns a `string`)

```
hourlyWage = int(input('Hourly Wage?'))
```

Answer (score -3):

Edit: *disclaimer: You can utilize the information this post provides safely now, proper edits were made after the comments (again).*

I should clarify that <s>using `eval` can be risky in other environments since it allows arbitrary code to be executed. Be sure to check out the commented lines in the code below.</s>

don't use `eval` in your code. Ever (unless you know what you're doing and have no choice).

---

By default the input returned from calling `input()` is a string. Call `eval`/ `float`/ `int` on the input to convert it to a number to be able to perform arithmetic operations on input.

```py
# you could use whatever function you want for conversion, but remember the use-cases for each one
# calling eval on random strings is dangerous in non-testing environments since it can cause any valid code the user wants at all to be run

hourlyWage = float(input('Hourly Wage?')) 
weeklyHours = float(input('Weekly Hours?'))
weeklyWage = hourlyWage * weeklyHours
print(weeklyWage)
```

Comment: Yikes don't use eval. Can run code and is dangerous

Comment: oops, i assumed it would be used for just the purpose shown in the OP

Comment: Using `eval` on user input is very bad advice.  There are better ways to convert an input string to a number.

Comment: "Eval is evil". This is a horrible and extremely dangerous way of doing a simple `float(x)` conversion.

Comment: I've edited to clarify that it was meant to be used only in the provided example. I fear I might be too late judging by the downvotes

Comment: Doesn't matter.  `eval` is best avoided at all costs, you don't want to get in the habit of using it.

Comment: Right you are, should've kept it in my mind OP is "new" and clarified extensively. Luckily you guys prevented this to be taken as advocation for it's usage.

Comment: The source of the downvotes is telling anyone ever to parse strings into numbers with `eval`. Noting that it's a bad idea doesn't turn it into a good idea.

Comment: I can't do anything more than say "don't use it" and the exact reason why. OP asked for some ways to do it and that's what I gave him (in a way). Edit: I've made edits that might render this a good idea.

Comment: It's all good.  This code is just for myself on my computer, just practicing.  I enjoy all the comments.  Now I'm trying to figure out how to convert an inputted str to a converted int with rounding.  Converting to str worked through.

Comment: Round to what exactly? You mean you want to convert the integer you get from calling `int()` on the string to an integer? It's already rounded to the whole number so can you specify how you want to round it (or am I just misinterpreting the question because I haven't slept in a long time) ?